# visual c++ 2010 debugging problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

When I debug the my game, it works.  But if I open my game's exe file that is stored in my project debug file, it shows as being 3 days old.  The file is not getting updated.

Any ideas why?

Comment: There may be multiple copies of these files.  Are you sure you're grabbing the right one?  What if you (back it up first) blow away the file?  If you rebuild, does it show up again?

Comment: Is it a single exe or are you building libraries/dlls which are used by the executable?

Comment: @merlyn i deleted the file and rebuild my project and it showed again but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> Project->Properties->Linker->Command
>   Line

and check the value of

> /OUT:

field. It probably should be different from the "debug" folder that you are checking.

Ensure that you are checking it appropriately for "Debug" and "Release" configurations